# Can Real Sense post processing be enabled through ROS?

Tags: c++, computer-vision, ros, point-clouds, realsense

I am trying to clean some of the noise in the point clouds that I obtain using a Intel RealSense D435 camera. In particular, I have noticed that the edges in these point clouds tend to be smoothed out to curves which is making segementation based on normals next to impossible.

I have done some research and found that the Intel Realsense SDK does include some post processing algorithms that aim to preserve edges and clean noise (see [here](https://dev.intelrealsense.com/docs/rs-post-processing)). The examples here, however, all seem to be for modifying the RealSense SDK using c++ and I don't see how I would implement them into ROS.

My question is: is it possible to implement these post processing algorithms using ROS? Currently, I start a camera stream using the `rs_camera.launch` file, but I don't see any parameters I can set here to enable these post-processing methods. Is there a separate node that I can run for this post processing?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have to create your own filtering node.

You can have this launch file running a node that publishes a `sensor_msgs::PointCloud2` and then create another one that will convert this message type to `rs2::pointcloud` and use this in your filters as in the [`rs-post-processing tutorial`](https://dev.intelrealsense.com/docs/rs-post-processing). After the filtering, you should convert the `rs2::pointcloud` back to `sensor_msgs::PointCloud2`.

Later on, it might be interesting to take a look at [`nodelets`](http://wiki.ros.org/nodelet) to improve your filtering pipeline, so you can separate the filters in different `nodelets` and use them in other cases as well.

In that sense, `ROS` is just a way for you to send/receive messages over different nodes.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @ignacio . I am trying to apply your suggested approach, but have not been able to find any way to convert between a `sensor_msgs::PointCloud2` to a `rs2::pointcloud`.  Do you have any experience with this or could you link the proper documentation? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else wishes to do something similar in the future, I managed to achieve this by creating a new camera driver node that directly performed the filtering on the `rs2::pointcloud` clouds that are read by the RealSense. I then convert these back to PCL point clouds and then `sensor_msgs::PoinCloud2` clouds so I can publish them.

If anyone is interested in this, I can set up a GitHub repository with my code.